# Why might I not be getting jQuery global ajax events when using jquery-ujs and Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Example:

```
$('form').on('ajax:success', function() {
 /* fired */
});

$('form').on('ajaxSuccess', function() {
 /* not fired */
});
```

'ajax:success' documented here : https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Reading the jQuery documentation on the ajax events leads me to believe that *any* dom element is eligible for the events (ie: ajaxSuccess). There does not seem to be any documentation in jquery-ujs that would indicate that the "normal" jquery ajax events are not fired.

jQuery Doc Excerpt http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

> **Global Events**
>
> These events are broadcast to all elements in the DOM, triggering any handlers which may be listening. You can listen for these events like so:"

Comment: Did you try `$(document).ajaxSuccess` ?

Comment: Of course that works, but that doesn't help me trying to get the event to fire on a specific element (as pointed out in my original post that included official jQuery documentation).

Comment: The 'rails' ujs specified events are only triggered on the 'form' element (checked the source). The original jQuery events (not sure why they are or why there is no documentation) that should be fired on any DOM element, are not (for me).

Comment: ajax:success is triggered in the element by ujs. ajaxSuccess is a global AJAX event, name suggest something global :p

Comment: uhh... check the jQuery doc page that I linked. Perhaps my reading comprehension is lacking.

Comment: did you add the jquery-rails gem in your gemfile? :)

Comment: Why would I be getting the 'ajax:success' event?